# Java collection : Map getting updated while using fail-safe iterator

Tags: java, collections

I was working on analyzing fail-safe iterators with Maps and verifying, if we are updating the keyset, will the operation happen on the clone or the actual map

```
private static void failSafeIterator() {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    map.put("a", "one");
    map.put("b", "two");
    Iterator<String> keyIterator=map.keySet().iterator();
    while(keyIterator.hasNext()){
        String key=keyIterator.next();
        System.out.println(key+":"+map.get(key));
        map.put("c", "three");
        map.put("q", "four");
        map.put("W", "five");

    }
    System.out.println(map.get("q"));

}
```

As per the above code snippet,

> the addition of c,q and w should have happened on the clone and not on
>   the actual collection

But i can see the update happening over the collection.

Also the output is a bit confusing as not all the key value pairs are printed, even though the key is present in the map.

***Output:***

```
a:one 
b:two
c:three
W:five
four
```

Comment: According to JDK 8 docs, `keySet()` "Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map." so no clone involved. The iterator of the set is [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly).

Comment: Where did you get "clone" from?

Comment: There is no implicit clone operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't understand what *weakly consistent* iterator stands for, when using `keySet().iterator()`, specifically this part of the documentation:

> they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Imagine a case like this: you are iterating a `ConcurrentHashMap` and printing whatever it has. Once you have seen a certain bucket and showed all of it's elements, you move to the next one, also updating the (suppose you add a `key-value` pair to it) previous one. Updates to that previous one are not going to be shown, although they do exist.

After your loop, you can do :

```
System.out.println(map);
```

And see that everything is now present.